# iOS: why some app can restore the account info when reinstalled

Tags: ios

Some apps, If you have ever used it on your iPhone once and then uninstalled it, the next time you install the app, the app can still retrieve your info that you filled out before you uninstalled it last time.

How does the app do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because they save account information on the keychain. 
Data stored in the keychain persist even if you uninstall the application, they are only removed if you perform a full restore of the device, or you remove by yourself.
This is a complete different behavior respect to `NSUserDefault` that is removed within the application deletion.
Data in keychain can also be shared between applications (if you implement it in the correct way) that use a similar bundle identifiers.